# How-to ORDER by DATE with this query

Tags: php

I am trying to change this query to order it by the date correctly.

This line works, but doesn't order all dates correct. It order by Year and not by days and months.

```
$query = mysql_query
("SELECT `date` FROM `table` WHERE `day` LIKE '%$row->period$row->friday%' AND date != '' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
        echo $row->date;
```

I created this, but the echo stays empty. What did I do wrong?

```
$query = mysql_query
("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') as `date2` FROM `table` WHERE `day` LIKE '%$row->period$row->friday%' AND date != '' ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)){
    echo $row->date2;
```

Comment: Try to change `LIKE '%$row->period$row->friday%'` to `LIKE '%{$row->period}{$row->friday}%'`

Comment: Also add an `i` to the `mysql` (`mysqli_*`)

Comment: Changing the '%$ to '%{ doesnt work. Adding i gives: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Answer (score 0):

The syntax was wrong.

```
      SELECT `date` FROM `table`
      WHERE `day` LIKE '%".$row->period."%'
      OR day like '%".$row->period."%' AND date != '' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1")
```

Comment: It works like this now. But it doesn't order it by DATE correctly.

Comment: I need help to implent the DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') so all dates are following up correctly.

Comment: of give you DB schema and query

Comment: Those can be seen in the Topic Start.